# OpenShift build config - push to docker.io

Tags: docker, openshift

Im trying to build a Dockerfile using OpenShifts Build Config.

The actual build completes successfully.

I have set the build config to push the resulting image to dockerhub. I've supplied a secret that contains my username and password to docker.io - and have double checked the credentials.

Yet when I run this I get the following error:

```
Pushing image hughestech/grpcdev ... error: build error: Failed to
push image: unauthorized: authentication required
```

**Build Config yml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: BuildConfig
metadata:
  annotations:
    openshift.io/generated-by: OpenShiftNewApp
  creationTimestamp: '2017-09-11T20:32:47Z'
  labels:
    app: grpcdev
  name: grpcdev
  namespace: testproject
  resourceVersion: '72394'
  selfLink: /oapi/v1/namespaces/testproject/buildconfigs/grpcdev
  uid: 5f70c545-9730-11e7-ab81-002421dde3d7
spec:
  nodeSelector: null
  output:
    pushSecret:
      name: dockhub-hughestech
    to:
      kind: DockerImage
      name: hughestech/grpcdev
  postCommit: {}
  resources: {}
  runPolicy: Serial
  source:
    git:
      uri: 'https://github.com/hughestech/grpcdev.git'
    type: Git
  strategy:
    dockerStrategy:
      from:
        kind: ImageStreamTag
        name: 'ubuntu:17.04'
    type: Docker
  triggers:
    - github:
        secret: gOH6EcI9bDDJu_P51gL5
      type: GitHub
    - generic:
        secret: PfAkvrk8xWVgWhVMk77V
      type: Generic
    - imageChange:
        lastTriggeredImageID: >-
          i386/ubuntu@sha256:22021496a6dd003b7fdc264985a578fb771edafa4cc9f790dd5e4967823567b2
      type: ImageChange
    - type: ConfigChange
status:
  lastVersion: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a new secret, and used `https://index.docker.io/v1/` for the url, and linked it to the `Builder` service account.